# File explorer/manager with GUI that displays the file count for each subfolder

Tags: file-management

I am looking for a graphical file explorer/manager that can display the file count for each subfolder, just like [Explorer++](https://explorerplusplus.com/) (and [other CLI solutions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7069/903)) can display the folder size for each subfolder:

[image]

Free if possible. I'm looking for solutions for Windows 7, Linux and Mac OS X (it's OK if a program only works on one OS).

Comment: Wouldn’t the "file count" be the number of files included in the folder? And your screenshot shows the totalized file size of the included files?

Comment: @Unor Yes exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can use [Folder Size Explorer](https://www.folder-size-explorer.com/download-folder-size-explorer.shtml) ([mirror](https://archive.org/details/folder-size)):

- gratis
- display the file count for each subfolder:
- Windows 10, 8, 7, Vista

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

One may use [TreeSize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TreeSize):

- not gratis
- display the file count for each subfolder
- Windows 10

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One may use [Total Commander Ultima Prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Commander):

- not gratis
- display the file count for each subfolder
- Windows 10

See the `All` column:

[image]

It has a plug-in for file count: `[=dirsizecalc.File Count]` (which is what the `All` column uses):

[image]

[image]

[image]